# Laravel 5 How to check password reset token if it exists in password_resets

Tags: laravel, hash, passwords

consider this scenario :

- User receives a reset password link by email.
- He clicks the 'reset password' link in his email and he will be redirected to password reset page that only he has access to due to the token in the URL . As you all know this token is stored in password_resets table with the email of the user .

I want to make the access to this page concerns only the user that clicked to the link in his email , so i have to compare the token in the URL with the token stored in 'password_resets' table ,and as Laravel uses a Hasher to encrypt the token before storing it and can't compare the two tokens .
Do you have any ideas how to fix this ?

Comment: Why do you need to compare the token manually? Laravel does that for you.

Comment: yeah i know but i want to give access to reset password page to the only the user who have a token that exists in my database , let's take this example : suppose the user who clicked the reset button in the email he reseved will be redirected to this url : www.example.com/password/reset/123456 ,  i want to let only him who sees this page because this token is valid and exists in DB , and when an other user types  : www.example.com/password/reset/123 for example he will see an error messages telling him that this token doesn't exist in DB , that's why i want to compare both Tokens .

Comment: The one who opens the link needs to again enter the email address with which the token is being compared. If you can guess the token exactly as it is given I will give you money :) Unless you have access to the inbox for the same user.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , but i don't him to retype his email i wnt him to access only the page with 2 inputs , enter password , the same way that's implemented in stackoverflow's system ,

Answer (score 0):

simply get the token from the url and hash it then compared the hashed token with the token in the database. This is how passwords are checked the hashed passwords in the database are not reversible you compare the hashes not the plain text password

Comment: Does laravel uses the same hasher for passwords and tokens ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Hash function built into Laravel, not sure what system your token generator is using but chances are it is using the Hash function in Laravel